# How to add arrays elementwise in pine script?

Tags: pine-script

Say we have two arrays in pine script: how do we add those arrays elementwise?

Example:

```
ETH = request.security("CRYPTOCAP:BTC", 'D', [open,high,low, close])
BTC = request.security("GLASSNODE:ETH_SUPPLY*INDEX:ETHUSD", 'D', [open,high,low, close])

TOTAL = ETH+BTC
```

Result:

```
*Syntax error: Variables of array type are not supported!*
```

EDIT: I know that you can add each component separately. But the point of this question is whether there  is a way to avoid doing that (in this case, you need four lines of code instead of one if you add element-by-element )

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting OHLC for each product, you will have to save them in separate variables first. Then you can add any of them, example below

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Add Prices",overlay=false,max_lines_count=500)
[ETHO,ETHH,ETHL,ETHC] = request.security("CRYPTOCAP:BTC", 'D', [open,high,low, close])
[BTCO,BTCH,BTCL,BTCC] = request.security("GLASSNODE:ETH_SUPPLY*INDEX:ETHUSD", 'D', [open,high,low, close])
TOTAL = ETHC+BTCC
plot(TOTAL)
```

**Edit**
We should not receive tuple values in single variable, As per the documentation at https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Type_system.html#tuples

> The result of a function such as calcSumAndMult() that returns a tuple
> must be assigned to a tuple declaration, i.e., a set of
> comma-separated list of new variables that will receive the values
> returned by the function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this does not answer the question I asked - I want to add the arrays. I already know I can add each component, but the point of adding arrays is to avoid having to perform operations component-by-component which really bloats the code.

Comment: So maybe the only way to do this would be to define your own functions for array operations?

Comment: Function will not allow input in tuple format

Comment: Perhaps you just write a function that takes a pair of series and returns the sum and put that in a library, then you can call it when you need it.